# Windows Server 2019 auditing removed as soon as applied

Tags: security, group-policy, audit, windows-server-2019

I've got a Windows Server 2019 domain controller with a GPO applying auditing on logon events. RSOP shows it is applied, however, if I look at the event logs, the moment it applies I can see that it is removed by SYSTEM. Why is this happening? How do I force auditing on this event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/676752/audit-policy-being-overwritten-by-something) but the link is dead and in an effort for future users I will post the answer I found.

> So there was an interesting case which floated my way the other day.
>
> The Audit policies in the domain controllers policy was set to the following, and there >were no other policies blocking or changing these.
>
> ---image of audit directory service access success GPO result
>
> After a policy update the following events were logged:
>
> ---image of auditing success removed event summary
>
> In addition, auditpol /get /category:* simply would show no auditing after policy update:
>
> ---image of cmd prompt showing no auditing
>
> So,  where was this crazy thing being overwritten? It wasn’t in the policies, since we checked all of them carefully for inheritance etc..
>
> Looking at where a client actually stores audit policy may give us a clue (C:\Windows\system32\grouppolicy\machine\microsoft\windows nt\audit\audit.csv  and C:\Windows\security)
>
> But there was nothing there of interest.  So, the last place to look was the sysvol data:
>
> M:\SYSVOL\domain\Policies{CEF3323C-FD89-4C03-9410-18F7A4922E5A}\Machine\microsoft\windows nt\Audit
>
> Aha! Under here was the .CSV file with the headings  - but no configuration data in it!
>
> --image of the csv file
>
> We removed this file and now audit policies flowed properly to the DCs and audit event were generated.
>
> Odd. It turns out that they had applied the policies via a GPOBackup and perhaps something had occurred prior to the backup.
>
> Anyway – hope it helps someone someday

Author: Steve Patrick (spat)

Here is a link to the archive of the [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20130720094447/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spatdsg/archive/2011/06/06/audit-policy-not-registering-audits.aspx)

Thanks Steve, it helped me 9 years later.